# how to use cloudnary in laravel

Tags: php, laravel

im encountering an issue with integrating Cloudinary into my Laravel project. I'm using the Cloudder package (jrm2k6/cloudder) for Laravel, but when trying to upload images, I'm getting the following error:

Error: Class "Cloudinary" not found in file C:\xampp\htdocs\Vitacon\VitacomBack\vendor\jrm2k6\cloudder\src\JD\Cloudder\CloudderServiceProvider.php on line 46

#0 C:\xampp\htdocs\Vitacon\VitacomBack\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Container\Container.php(873): JD\Cloudder\CloudderServiceProvider->JD\Cloudder{closure}(Object(Illuminate\Foundation\Application), Array)
#1 C:\xampp\htdocs\Vitacon\VitacomBack\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Container\Container.php(758): Illuminate\Container\Container->build(Object(Closure))
#2 C:\xampp\htdocs\Vitacon\VitacomBack\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Foundation\Application.php(851): Illuminate\Container\Container->resolve('cloudder', Array, true)
#3 C:\xampp\htdocs\Vitacon\VitacomBack\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Container\Container.php(694): Illuminate\Foundation\Application->resolve('cloudder', Array)
#4 C:\xampp\htdocs\Vitacon\VitacomBack\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Foundation\Application.php(836): Illuminate\Container\Container->make('cloudder', Array)
#5 C:\xampp\htdocs\Vitacon\VitacomBack\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Container\Container.php(1419): Illuminate\Foundation\Application->make('cloudder')
#6 C:\xampp\htdocs\Vitacon\VitacomBack\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Support\Facades\Facade.php(198): Illuminate\Container\Container->offsetGet('cloudder')
#7 C:\xampp\htdocs\Vitacon\VitacomBack\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Support\Facades\Facade.php(166): Illuminate\Support\Facades\Facade::resolveFacadeInstance('cloudder')
#8 C:\xampp\htdocs\Vitacon\VitacomBack\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Support\Facades\Facade.php(255): Illuminate\Support\Facades\Facade::getFacadeRoot()
#9 C:\xampp\htdocs\Vitacon\VitacomBack\app\Http\Controllers\ImageUploadController.php(16): Illuminate\Support\Facades\Facade::__callStatic('upload', Array)
#10 C:\xampp\htdocs\Vitacon\VitacomBack\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Routing\Controller.php(54): App\Http\Controllers\ImageUploadController->uploadImage(Object(Illuminate\Http\Request))
#11 C:\xampp\htdocs\Vitacon\VitacomBack\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Routing\ControllerDispatcher.php(45): Illuminate\Routing\Controller->callAction('uploadImage', Array)
#12 C:\xampp\htdocs\Vitacon\VitacomBack\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Routing\Route.php(262): Illuminate\Routing\ControllerDispatcher->dispatch(Object(Illuminate\Routing\Route), Object(App\Http\Controllers\ImageUploadController), 'uploadImage')
#13 C:\xampp\htdocs\Vitacon\VitacomBack\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Routing\Route.php(205): Illuminate\Routing\Route->runController()
#14 C:\xampp\htdocs\Vitacon\VitacomBack\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Routing\Router.php(721): Illuminate\Routing\Route->run()
#15 C:\xampp\htdocs\Vitacon\VitacomBack\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Pipeline\Pipeline.php(128): Illuminate\Routing\Router->Illuminate\Routing{closure}(Object(Illuminate\Http\Request))
#16 C:\xampp\htdocs\Vitacon\VitacomBack\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Routing\Middleware\SubstituteBindings.php(50): Illuminate\Pipeline\Pipeline->Illuminate\Pipeline{closure}(Object(Illuminate\Http\Request))
#17 C:\xampp\htdocs\Vitacon\VitacomBack\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Pipeline\Pipeline.php(167): Illuminate\Routing\Middleware\SubstituteBindings->handle(Object(Illuminate\Http\Request), Object(Closure))
#18 C:\xampp\htdocs\Vitacon\VitacomBack\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Routing\Middleware\ThrottleRequests.php(127): Illuminate\Pipeline\Pipeline->Illuminate\Pipeline{closure}(Object(Illuminate\Http\Request))
#19 C:\xampp\htdocs\Vitacon\VitacomBack\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Routing\Middleware\ThrottleRequests.php(103): Illuminate\Routing\Middleware\ThrottleRequests->handleRequest(Object(Illuminate\Http\Request), Object(Closure), Array)
#20 C:\xampp\htdocs\Vitacon\VitacomBack\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Routing\Middleware\ThrottleRequests.php(55): Illuminate\Routing\Middleware\ThrottleRequests->handleRequestUsingNamedLimiter(Object(Illuminate\Http\Request), Object(Closure), 'api', Object(Closure))
#21 C:\xampp\htdocs\Vitacon\VitacomBack\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Pipeline\Pipeline.php(167): Illuminate\Routing\Middleware\ThrottleRequests->handle(Object(Illuminate\Http\Request), Object(Closure), 'api')
#22 C:\xampp\htdocs\Vitacon\VitacomBack\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Pipeline\Pipeline.php(103): Illuminate\Pipeline\Pipeline->Illuminate\Pipeline{closure}(Object(Illuminate\Http\Request))
#23 C:\xampp\htdocs\Vitacon\VitacomBack\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Routing\Router.php(723): Illuminate\Pipeline\Pipeline->then(Object(Closure))
#24 C:\xampp\htdocs\Vitacon\VitacomBack\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Routing\Router.php(698): Illuminate\Routing\Router->runRouteWithinStack(Object(Illuminate\Routing\Route), Object(Illuminate\Http\Request))
#25 C:\xampp\htdocs\Vitacon\VitacomBack\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Routing\Router.php(662): Illuminate\Routing\Router->runRoute(Object(Illuminate\Http\Request), Object(Illuminate\Routing\Route))
#26 C:\xampp\htdocs\Vitacon\VitacomBack\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Routing\Router.php(651): Illuminate\Routing\Router->dispatchToRoute(Object(Illuminate\Http\Request))
#27 C:\xampp\htdocs\Vitacon\VitacomBack\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Foundation\Http\Kernel.php(167): Illuminate\Routing\Router->dispatch(Object(Illuminate\Http\Request))
#28 C:\xampp\htdocs\Vitacon\VitacomBack\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Pipeline\Pipeline.php(128): Illuminate\Foundation\Http\Kernel->Illuminate\Foundation\Http{closure}(Object(Illuminate\Http\Request))
#29 C:\xampp\htdocs\Vitacon\VitacomBack\vendor\fruitcake\laravel-cors\src\HandleCors.php(52): Illuminate\Pipeline\Pipeline->Illuminate\Pipeline{closure}(Object(Illuminate\Http\Request))
#30 C:\xampp\htdocs\Vitacon\VitacomBack\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Pipeline\Pipeline.php(167): Fruitcake\Cors\HandleCors->handle(Object(Illuminate\Http\Request), Object(Closure))
#31 C:\xampp\htdocs\Vitacon\VitacomBack\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Foundation\Http\Middleware\TransformsRequest.php(21): Illuminate\Pipeline\Pipeline->Illuminate\Pipeline{closure}(Object(Illuminate\Http\Request))
#32 C:\xampp\htdocs\Vitacon\VitacomBack\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Foundation\Http\Middleware\ConvertEmptyStringsToNull.php(31): Illuminate\Foundation\Http\Middleware\TransformsRequest->handle(Object(Illuminate\Http\Request), Object(Closure))
#33 C:\xampp\htdocs\Vitacon\VitacomBack\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Pipeline\Pipeline.php(167): Illuminate\Foundation\Http\Middleware\ConvertEmptyStringsToNull->handle(Object(Illuminate\Http\Request), Object(Closure))
#34 C:\xampp\htdocs\Vitacon\VitacomBack\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Foundation\Http\Middleware\TransformsRequest.php(21): Illuminate\Pipeline\Pipeline->Illuminate\Pipeline{closure}(Object(Illuminate\Http\Request))
#35 C:\xampp\htdocs\Vitacon\VitacomBack\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Foundation\Http\Middleware\TrimStrings.php(40): Illuminate\Foundation\Http\Middleware\TransformsRequest->handle(Object(Illuminate\Http\Request), Object(Closure))
#36 C:\xampp\htdocs\Vitacon\VitacomBack\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Pipeline\Pipeline.php(167): Illuminate\Foundation\Http\Middleware\TrimStrings->handle(Object(Illuminate\Http\Request), Object(Closure))
#37 C:\xampp\htdocs\Vitacon\VitacomBack\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Foundation\Http\Middleware\ValidatePostSize.php(27): Illuminate\Pipeline\Pipeline->Illuminate\Pipeline{closure}(Object(Illuminate\Http\Request))
#38 C:\xampp\htdocs\Vitacon\VitacomBack\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Pipeline\Pipeline.php(167): Illuminate\Foundation\Http\Middleware\ValidatePostSize->handle(Object(Illuminate\Http\Request), Object(Closure))
#39 C:\xampp\htdocs\Vitacon\VitacomBack\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Foundation\Http\Middleware\PreventRequestsDuringMaintenance.php(86): Illuminate\Pipeline\Pipeline->Illuminate\Pipeline{closure}(Object(Illuminate\Http\Request))
#40 C:\xampp\htdocs\Vitacon\VitacomBack\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Pipeline\Pipeline.php(167): Illuminate\Foundation\Http\Middleware\PreventRequestsDuringMaintenance->handle(Object(Illuminate\Http\Request), Object(Closure))
#41 C:\xampp\htdocs\Vitacon\VitacomBack\vendor\fruitcake\laravel-cors\src\HandleCors.php(52): Illuminate\Pipeline\Pipeline->Illuminate\Pipeline{closure}(Object(Illuminate\Http\Request))
#42 C:\xampp\htdocs\Vitacon\VitacomBack\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Pipeline\Pipeline.php(167): Fruitcake\Cors\HandleCors->handle(Object(Illuminate\Http\Request), Object(Closure))
#43 C:\xampp\htdocs\Vitacon\VitacomBack\vendor\fideloper\proxy\src\TrustProxies.php(57): Illuminate\Pipeline\Pipeline->Illuminate\Pipeline{closure}(Object(Illuminate\Http\Request))
#44 C:\xampp\htdocs\Vitacon\VitacomBack\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Pipeline\Pipeline.php(167): Fideloper\Proxy\TrustProxies->handle(Object(Illuminate\Http\Request), Object(Closure))
#45 C:\xampp\htdocs\Vitacon\VitacomBack\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Pipeline\Pipeline.php(103): Illuminate\Pipeline\Pipeline->Illuminate\Pipeline{closure}(Object(Illuminate\Http\Request))
#46 C:\xampp\htdocs\Vitacon\VitacomBack\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Foundation\Http\Kernel.php(142): Illuminate\Pipeline\Pipeline->then(Object(Closure))
#47 C:\xampp\htdocs\Vitacon\VitacomBack\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Foundation\Http\Kernel.php(111): Illuminate\Foundation\Http\Kernel->sendRequestThroughRouter(Object(Illuminate\Http\Request))
#48 C:\xampp\htdocs\Vitacon\VitacomBack\public\index.php(52): Illuminate\Foundation\Http\Kernel->handle(Object(Illuminate\Http\Request))
#49 C:\xampp\htdocs\Vitacon\VitacomBack\server.php(21): require_once('C:\xampp\htdocs...')
#50 {main}.

Here's how I'm attempting to upload the image in my ImageUploadController:

I've also checked that the Cloudder service provider is registered correctly in my config/app.php.

Can someone help me understand why I'm getting this error and how to resolve it? Am I missing any steps in configuring the Cloudder package or using the Cloudinary SDK in Laravel?

Thanks in advance for any insights or suggestions!

I tried to integrate Cloudinary into my Laravel project using the Cloudder package (jrm2k6/cloudder). I followed the installation steps outlined in the package documentation and configured my Cloudinary credentials in the .env file.

Next, I attempted to upload an image using the uploadImage method in my ImageUploadController. However, when I executed the upload, I encountered the error message

``Error: Class "Cloudinary" not found in file C:\xampp\htdocs\Vitacon\VitacomBack\vendor\jrm2k6\cloudder\src\JD\Cloudder\CloudderServiceProvider.php on line 46

#0 C:\xampp\htdocs\Vitacon\VitacomBack\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Container\Container.php(873): JD\Cloudder\CloudderServiceProvider->JD\Cloudder{closure}(Object(Illuminate\Foundation\Application), Array)
`

I expected the image to be successfully uploaded to Cloudinary without any errors. However, the error message indicates that the Cloudinary class is not being found, even though I have installed the Cloudder package via Composer and registered the service provider correctly.

I've double-checked my configuration settings, ensured that the Cloudder service provider is registered in config/app.php, and verified that the Cloudinary credentials in the .env file are correct.

Despite these efforts, the error persists, and I'm unable to upload images to Cloudinary using the Cloudder package as intended.

I would appreciate any insights or suggestions on how to resolve this issue. Thank you!

Comment: Did you specify the `use JD\Cloudder\Facades\Cloudder`

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.